# How to load partial page using apache tiles with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, partial-views, tiles, apache-tiles

I am using apache tiles for spring mvc.

The layout looks like:
[image]

The tiles.xml file is :

```
<!-- Default Layout -->
<definition name="default_layout" template="/jsp/layout/default_layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/jsp/header_footer/top_bar.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/jsp/left_menu/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body1" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="right_pane" value="/jsp/right_pane/right_pane.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/jsp/header_footer/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="home" extends="default_layout">
    <put-attribute name="body1" value="/jsp/home/home.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Now it is working fine, except for the scenario, when I clicked on menu then the whole page get reloaded. And I lost the section of menu where I clicked.

**The menu is implemented as**

```
<ul>
 <li></li>
 ........
 ........
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

So, is there any way to load the tiles partially, or any work around that I can use to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

in your `tiles.xml` file

```
<definition name="templatename"
            template="/WEB-INF/pages/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/pages/includes/header.jsp" />
     <put-attribute name="sidebar" value="WEB-INF/pages/includes/sidebar.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="rightsidebar" value="/WEB-INF/pages/includes/rightsidebar.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/pages/includes/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

create page for header, footer, sidebar under right directory mentioned in `tiles.xml` and also create template name by `layout.jsp` with the tag

```
<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
<tiles:insertAttribute name="sidebar" />
<tiles:insertAttribute name="rightsidebar" />
<tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
<tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
```

then you can invoke the page through spring-mvc controller url-pattern.

add this to tiles.xml

```
<definition name="/dosomething" extends="templatename">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="dosomething" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/login/dosomething.jsp" />
</definition>
```

for partial body load create a page `dosomething.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

The Only way of Achieving Partial rendering in your case is using Jquery's Load method.

in your sidebar.jsp in the anchor tags write an onclick="test()",

```
function test() {

$("#Maincontent").load("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/yourcontrollerMapping");

}
```

you can have a div(Maincontent) to specify the area you want to load your content in your layout.jsp (Since Apache Tiles will refresh all elements including the sidebar).